# c- How is an expression evaluated when it has Comma operator?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, operators, increment

I'm getting **b = 40** but I can't figure out how the expression b is evaluated in this program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int a = 8, b;
  b = (a++, ++a, a<<2);
  
  printf("%d",b);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: 'b = (a++, ++a, a<<2);'.............I have to ask............why?

Comment: Didn't get what you mean, but I suppose you meant the purpose of that evaluation. There is no purpose just an example of the comma operator.

Answer (score 0):

The comma operator is evaluated left to right, and the value of the expression the the last value which in this case is `(8+1+1)*4 = 40`.